# How to save weights of a neural network

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, neural-network

I am facing problem in saving weights of a trained neural network in a text file.
Here is my code

```html
def nNetwork(trainingData,filename):

    lamda = 1
    input_layer = 1200
    output_layer = 10
    hidden_layer = 25
    X=trainingData[0]
    y=trainingData[1]
    theta1 = randInitializeWeights(1200,25)
    theta2 = randInitializeWeights(25,10)
    m,n = np.shape(X)
    yk = recodeLabel(y,output_layer)
    theta = np.r_[theta1.T.flatten(), theta2.T.flatten()]

    X_bias = np.r_[np.ones((1,X.shape[0])), X.T]
    #conjugate gradient algo
    result = scipy.optimize.fmin_cg(computeCost,fprime=computeGradient,x0=theta,args=(input_layer,hidden_layer,output_layer,X,y,lamda,yk,X_bias),maxiter=100,disp=True,full_output=True )
    print result[1]  #min value
    theta1,theta2 = paramUnroll(result[0],input_layer,hidden_layer,output_layer)
    counter = 0
    for i in range(m):
        prediction = predict(X[i],theta1,theta2)
        actual = y[i]
        if(prediction == actual):
            counter+=1
    print  str(counter *100/m) + '% accuracy'

    data = {"Theta1":[theta1],
            "Theta2":[theta2]}
    op=open(filename,'w')
    json.dump(data,op)
    op.close()
```

```html
def paramUnroll(params,input_layer,hidden_layer,labels):
    theta1_elems = (input_layer+1)*hidden_layer
    theta1_size = (input_layer+1,hidden_layer)
    theta2_size = (hidden_layer+1,labels)
    theta1 = params[:theta1_elems].T.reshape(theta1_size).T
    theta2 = params[theta1_elems:].T.reshape(theta2_size).T
    return theta1, theta2
```

I am getting the following error 
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")

Please give a solution or any other way to save the weights so that I can easily load them In some other code.

Comment: Either theta1 or theta2, or both, is not JSON serializable.  They are objects returned by the function paramUnroll.  So what sort of object are they?

Comment: @PaulCornelius  theta1 and theta2 are numpy array

Comment: Try `theta1.tolist()`. Just remember to initialize the `numpy.array` again after loading the written list from the file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to save numpy arrays to pure text is to execute [`numpy.savetxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) (and load it with [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)). However, if you want to save both using the JSON format you can write the files using a [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html) instance:

```
with StringIO as theta1IO:
    numpy.savetxt(theta1IO, theta1)
    data = {"theta1": theta1IO.getvalue() }
    # write as JSON as usual
```

You can do that with the other parameters as well.

To retrieve the data you can do:

```
# read data from JSON
with StringIO as theta1IO:
    theta1IO.write(data['theta1'])
    theta1 = numpy.loadtxt(theta1IO)
```

Comment: Can we save both the arrays as dictionaries in a single text file using numpy. savetxt

Comment: @IshankGulati If they have matching dimensions the documentation shows a way to do this, but then you would have to process the matrix in after np.loadtxt in order to separate both matrices.